# How to test with hardwired function

Tags: haskell, testing

My understanding is that code should be written without testing in mind, and that testing needs to bend to cater to the code. My problem is that I have a function `f1` that calls out for input data (a  Haskell `data` type) that is returned from another function `f2`. So how can I write a test case that provides **different** input data?

Of course I could add an arg to `f1` for the input, but after all that is catering to testing. It's actually messier than that, because `f1` is actually a [Plutus contract](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/04/13/plutus-what-you-need-to-know/), and the arg would need to be serialized to JSON -- all for the sake of testing. Alternatively, I could read the input from a file, and provide the filepath as an arg -- the arg is bad enough, but I don't want to go with a file if I don't have to.

**Note that `f1` is an http endpoint, and all testing code needs to go through an endpoint(s).**

```hs
data ActualData = ActualData String String Integer
newtype Input = Input [ActualData]

f1:: Contract () Schema Text () 
f1 = do
    let input = f2 
    ...

f2 :: Input -- to be determined in the future, currently unknown
f2 = Input
    [ ActualData "BlackRock" "pkh1" 10
    , ActualData "GreenRock" "pkh2" 20
    ]
```

Comment: I think I'd reject your premise.  Code should definitely be written with testing in mind - that doesn't mean that testing is the primary concern, but it's a first class stakeholder.

Comment: I find it odd that you say that "code should be written without testing in mind". In fact one of the key features of Haskell (and functional languages in general) is to encapsulate side-effects, and thus make it a lot easier to test.

Comment: Where does `f2` actually get the data from?

Comment: For example, define `iternalF1` and `f1 = internalF1 f2`. Then write tests on `internalF1`.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I update original question to show `f2`

Comment: But `f2` is constant. Is not clear what problem do you have with test `f1`?

Comment: @thirsty: testable code, is usually also better code, since it means you managed to subdivide your program in small subprograms that each do a simple thing. This is not only better for testing, but also better to later extend logic.

Comment: @freestyle Yes it's constant -- to be defined in the future. But currently I don't know what it is, and need to be ready for anything that compiles.

Comment: In my past life as a software assurance specialist, the development standards we worked with included "written for testability" and "designed for testability".

Answer (score 6):

I think the simplest is probably just to expose *two* functions. One accepts the input data as a plain old function input, and the other knows to use `f2`. So:

```
f1WithArg :: X -> Y
f1WithArg x = {- ... -}

f1 :: Y
f1 = f2 >>= f1WithArg -- or whatever
```

Then you would write all your tests in terms of `f1WithArg`, and just trust that `f1` doesn't do any interesting computation.

Alternatively, you could expose a single `f1` that takes a `Maybe X`, with a similar implementation pattern:

```
f1Auto :: Maybe X -> Y
f1Auto Nothing = f2 >>= f1Auto . Just -- or whatever
f1Auto (Just x) = {- ... -}
```

Some interface like that might be useful if you ever need to programmatically decide whether the input should come from `f2` or not, but that sounds like it's not the case for you.

Comment: Doesn't help -- I updated original question to indicate that all testing code needs to go through an endpoint(s).

Comment: @thirsty ...why? (And why doesn't the same approach, i.e. adding a new endpoint, work even if there *is* a good reason all testing must go through endpoints?)

Comment: I meant that for the sake of testing only, input must now be sent over the wire; whereas without testing, the endpoint would not take an arg.

Comment: @thirsty I don't understand how that statement is related to my questions.

Comment: My whole dilemma is that testing is driving the code design: I would not be sending anything over the wire if it were not for testing. And I am just wondering if in fact that's life, or perhaps I can have my cake and eat it too (test, but still send nothing over the wire).

Comment: @thirsty You demand that all testing be done over the wire, but that you don't do any testing over the wire?